# Split array object to nested array for each separator

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, reduce, key-value

I am trying to split the below array

```
{
    "Base/Brand/0101-color-brand-primary-red": "#fe414d",
    "Base/Brand/0106-color-brand-secondary-green": "#00e6c3",
    "Base/Brand/0102-color-brand-primary-light-gray": "#eaecf0",
    "Base/Brand/0107-color-brand-secondary-black": "#000000",
    "Base/Brand/0103-color-brand-primary-white": "#ffffff",
    "Base/Brand/0108-color-brand-secondary-dark-gray": "#b4b4b4",
    "Base/Brand/0104-color-brand-secondary-blue": "#079fff",
    "Base/Light/Extended/Red/0201-color-extended-900-red": "#7f1d1d",
    "Base/Brand/0105-color-brand-secondary-yellow": "#ffe63b",
    "Base/Light/Extended/Red/0202-color-extended-800-red": "#991b1b"
}
```

to something like this

```
{
  "Base": {
    "Brand": {
      "0101-color-brand-primary-red": "#fe414d",
      "0106-color-brand-secondary-green": "#00e6c3",
      "Light": {
        "Extended": {
          "Red": {
            "0201-color-extended-900-red": "#7f1d1d",
            "0202-color-extended-800-red": "#991b1b"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Basically I need to split array by '/' and create nested array
Please help how can I achieve this.

Comment: The presented structure is not an array but a flat (not nested) object of key value pairs.

Comment: Regarding especially the different approaches, are there any questions left?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.entries` to get all entries in the original object. Use `split('/')` to get an array of the object path keys in the output. Then use `reduce` on that path array to create levels inside the result, until the very last element in the path is reached. At this point, we set the last path element to the required color value.

```js
const d = {
  "Base/Brand/0101-color-brand-primary-red": "#fe414d",
  "Base/Brand/0106-color-brand-secondary-green": "#00e6c3",
  "Base/Brand/0102-color-brand-primary-light-gray": "#eaecf0",
  "Base/Brand/0107-color-brand-secondary-black": "#000000",
  "Base/Brand/0103-color-brand-primary-white": "#ffffff",
  "Base/Brand/0108-color-brand-secondary-dark-gray": "#b4b4b4",
  "Base/Brand/0104-color-brand-secondary-blue": "#079fff",
  "Base/Light/Extended/Red/0201-color-extended-900-red": "#7f1d1d",
  "Base/Brand/0105-color-brand-secondary-yellow": "#ffe63b",
  "Base/Light/Extended/Red/0202-color-extended-800-red": "#991b1b"
}

const r = Object.entries(d).reduce((a, [p,v]) => 
  (p.split('/').reduce((a,c,i,r) => 
    a[c] ??= i<(r.length-1) ? {} : v, a), a), {})

console.log(r)
```

Comment: You shouldn't give the complete answer/upvote to ppl who don't make any effort to solve the problem themselves or at least the don't post their attempt in the question. That will just promote lazyness

Answer (score 1):

Since the provided structure is a flat (not nested) object of key-value pairs (entries), one could start aggregating the OP's desired target data-structure by [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)ing the source-object's [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

The [*initial value*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#how_reduce_works_with_an_initial_value) of this outer `reduce` task will be an empty object (literal).

The [*reducer function*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#description) of the very same task does receive with each iteration the to be aggregated object reference (which in the very beginning is the initial value / the empty object). It also receives the current iteration's ***entry*** which is a [*key-value pair*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#return_value) provided as an array. The `key` actually is the ***key-path***, a string which can be further [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) at every occurring slash. The `value` is the ***path-value*** which has to be assigned as last value of any aggregated (partial) object reference.

Thus, one is in need of a second, nested, `reduce` task which does process each of the key-path' partial `key` values. The *initial value* will be always the base or root reference of the to be aggregated object. The inner `reduce` task does aggregate the received `node` reference by [either accessing an already existing node, or by creating a new (empty node) or by assigning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment) the final path-value to the last created node. It also always does pass this reference as current node into the next iteration step.

```js
const sampleData = {
  "Base/Brand/0101-color-brand-primary-red": "#fe414d",
  "Base/Brand/0106-color-brand-secondary-green": "#00e6c3",
  "Base/Brand/0102-color-brand-primary-light-gray": "#eaecf0",
  "Base/Brand/0107-color-brand-secondary-black": "#000000",
  "Base/Brand/0103-color-brand-primary-white": "#ffffff",
  "Base/Brand/0108-color-brand-secondary-dark-gray": "#b4b4b4",
  "Base/Brand/0104-color-brand-secondary-blue": "#079fff",
  "Base/Light/Extended/Red/0201-color-extended-900-red": "#7f1d1d",
  "Base/Brand/0105-color-brand-secondary-yellow": "#ffe63b",
  "Base/Light/Extended/Red/0202-color-extended-800-red": "#991b1b",
};

function createObjectFromKeyPartialsAndValues(data) {
  return Object
    .entries(data)
    .reduce((root, [keyPath, pathValue]) => {

      keyPath
        .split('/')
        .reduce((node, key, idx, keyList) => {

          const isLastKey = !keyList.hasOwnProperty(idx + 1);
          const value = isLastKey ? pathValue : {};

          const obj = (node[key] ??= value);
          return obj;

        }, root);

      return root;

    }, {});
}

console.log(
  createObjectFromKeyPartialsAndValues(sampleData)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, in the future, please share your own effort when asking a question.  I for one wouldn't answer until I saw your own approach if there weren't already decent answers here.

---

I keep handy a number of utility functions.  One of those is [hydrate](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a1243641%20hydrate&searchOn=3), which accepts an array of what I call `pathEntries` (similar to the result of `Object .entries`, but with an *array* of strings/integers representing the *path* rather than a single string for the property) and returns an object.  With that, we can write a very simple version of this function:

```js
const expand = (o) =>
  hydrate (Object .entries (o) .map (([k, v]) => [k.split('/'), v]))
```

`hydrate` is based on `setPath` which creates a copy (sharing as much as possible) of an object, with a new value at the given path, creating new nodes along the way.

For example,

```js
setPath 
  (['foo', 'bar', 0, 'baz']) 
  (42) 
  ({foo: {qux: {corge: 100, grault: 99}}, waldo: 0})
//=> {foo: {bar: [{baz: 42}], qux: {corge: 100, grault: 99}}, waldo: 0}
```

Put together, my solution would look like this:

```js
const setPath = ([p, ...ps]) => (v) => (o) =>
  p == undefined ? v : Object .assign (
    Array .isArray (o) || Number .isInteger (p) ? [] : {},
    {...o, [p]: setPath (ps) (v) ((o || {}) [p])}
  )

const hydrate = (xs) =>
  xs .reduce ((a, [p, v]) => setPath (p) (v) (a), {})

const expand = (o) =>
  hydrate (Object .entries (o) .map (([k, v]) => [k.split('/'), v]))

const flatData = {"Base/Brand/0101-color-brand-primary-red": "#fe414d", "Base/Brand/0106-color-brand-secondary-green": "#00e6c3", "Base/Brand/0102-color-brand-primary-light-gray": "#eaecf0", "Base/Brand/0107-color-brand-secondary-black": "#000000", "Base/Brand/0103-color-brand-primary-white": "#ffffff", "Base/Brand/0108-color-brand-secondary-dark-gray": "#b4b4b4", "Base/Brand/0104-color-brand-secondary-blue": "#079fff", "Base/Light/Extended/Red/0201-color-extended-900-red": "#7f1d1d", "Base/Brand/0105-color-brand-secondary-yellow": "#ffe63b", "Base/Light/Extended/Red/0202-color-extended-800-red": "#991b1b"}

console .log (expand (flatData))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with a recursive function like the one below. What it does is to split each path by "/" and then check them in a recursive manner and add each section to the output object if they're not already appended.

```js
const list = {
  "Base/Brand/0101-color-brand-primary-red": "#fe414d",
  "Base/Brand/0106-color-brand-secondary-green": "#00e6c3",
  "Base/Brand/0102-color-brand-primary-light-gray": "#eaecf0",
  "Base/Brand/0107-color-brand-secondary-black": "#000000",
  "Base/Brand/0103-color-brand-primary-white": "#ffffff",
  "Base/Brand/0108-color-brand-secondary-dark-gray": "#b4b4b4",
  "Base/Brand/0104-color-brand-secondary-blue": "#079fff",
  "Base/Light/Extended/Red/0201-color-extended-900-red": "#7f1d1d",
  "Base/Brand/0105-color-brand-secondary-yellow": "#ffe63b",
  "Base/Light/Extended/Red/0202-color-extended-800-red": "#991b1b",
};

const result = {};

Object.entries(list).forEach((entry) => {
  const path = entry[0]; // "Base/Brand/0101-color-brand-primary-red"
  const value = entry[1]; // "#fe414d"
  sections = path.split("/"); // ["Base", "Brand", "0101-color-brand-primary-red"]

  // start creating the output object using a recursive function
  sett(result, sections, sections[0], 0, sections.length, value);
});

function sett(parentObj, sections, currentSection, currentIndex, depth, value) {
  // stop if we've reached the end of the path
  if (currentIndex >= depth) return;

  // if not, check if this is the last section of the path
  const isLastSection = sections[currentIndex + 1] === undefined;

  // if there is not already an entry in result for this section (e.g  "Base" or "brand")
  if (!parentObj[currentSection])
    // if it's the end of the path (e.g one of the colors like 0101-color-brand-primary-red) assign it the value else assign {} to it
    parentObj[currentSection] = isLastSection ? value : {};

  // else go deeper in the path
  const nextSection = sections[currentIndex + 1];

  sett(
    parentObj[currentSection],
    sections,
    nextSection,
    currentIndex + 1,
    depth,
    value
  );
}

console.log(result);
```